# DAX and Data Modeling Issue - Filtering from one table to the other

Tags: powerbi, dax

[Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0pGf.png)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQayc.jpg)

[Example 2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCrI0.png)

[Example 2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viK2d.png)

I am working with three databases, but for this issue, only two are being considered.

I am referring to the tables in the picture.

The Prepayments and Income table are connected through Contract ID in the Contract (BW) table.

I also have a ‘DateTable’ which is a lookup table containing all the unique dates from Prepayments (Adjustment Date) and Income (Due Date) combined.

I want to get the value (Net Amount (Total)) in my Income Table when the Due Date is one date just before the Adjustment Date. In my example table, for this particular contract ID X, I have my Adjustment Date 01/12/2023.

To the adjustments table, I want to add:

Two new columns Prepayment Old and Prepayment New. In this example, Prepayment Old would be one date before adjustment → 156 and Prepayment New → 183.
Two other columns calculating Amount before Adjustment (1716) and Amount after Adjustment (2082)

I tried doing it using

CALCULATE ( MAX ( Prepayments[PrepaymentAdjustment] ), FILTER etc)

But it didn’t work and I think it’s because of the data model or the direction of the filtering and the connections.

If my data model is wrong, how to change it?

Comment: Missing picture(s) ?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you wanting to add Calculated Columns to the actual data tables? Or just have the columns added to the visual (via a Measure)?

Comment: @SamNseir Added to the visual via a measure :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a Measure like:

```
Income Before = 
  var adjustmentDate = MAX(Prepayments[ Adjustment Date])

  var prevIncome = 
    FILTER(
      Income,
      Income[ Due Date] < adjustmentDate 
    )

  var result = 
    CALCULATE(
      MAX( Income[Net Amount(Total)] ),
      TOPN(1, prevIncome , [ Due Date], DESC)
    )

  return result
```

Hopefully that will get you going.

---

Additional version if there are more than one Adjustments.

```
Income Before = 
  SUMX(
    DISTINCT(Prepayments[ Adjustment Date]),
    (
      var thisAdjDate = CALCULATE(MIN(Prepayments[ Adjustment Date]))
    
      var prevIncome = 
        FILTER(
          Income,
          Income[ Due Date] < thisAdjDate
        )

      var result = 
        CALCULATE(
          MAX( Income[Net Amount(Total)] ),
          TOPN(1, prevIncome , [ Due Date], DESC)
        )

      return result
    )
```

Comment: Thank you but that's not it. I want to get the value (Net Amount (Total)) in my Income Table when the Due Date is one date just before the Adjustment Date. These are from two different tables if you look at the picture. But I can't filter from one table to the other because of the relationship. So I think there is a problem with my data model.
Is there?

Comment: Updated the answer above to use the Income table. There isn't an issue with your data model as far as I can see, so long as you use the `'Contract (BW)'[Contract ID]` column in your visuals.

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you. It works when there is only one adjustment (for e.g., in the picture that I sent). But when there are more than one adjustment, it doesn't work. I don't think we can use MAX then, but instead VALUES. I'm not sure how to write it.

Comment: See the second version added to the answer above, hopefully that works for you.

Comment: Hi Sam,
Thank you but it doesn't work.
I added two pictures, example 2.0 and 2.1.

The values are Prepayment before are supposed to be:
01/01/2023 Prepayment Before 2230 and Prepayment After 1982
01/02/2023 Prepayment Before 1982 and Prepayment After 2389

Comment: Updated it, try it now.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. I still get 2230 for both adjustment dates. For the first one (01.01.2023), 2230 is correct but the second one (01.02.2023) should be 1982 as in example 2.0 and 2.1.

Comment: Could you share a link (via One Drive, Google Drive, Drop Box, or similar) to a sample PBIX. Remove sensitive data, just need sample data to reproduce and fix.